# Explicit expression of matrix $e^A$ where $A\in\mathfrak{so}(1,3) $

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\eta=$ diag$\,(-1,1,1,1) $. Consider the proper orthochronous Lorentz subgroup  $SO^+(1,3)$ which contains all matrix $L=(a_{ij})_{0\leq i,j\leq3}$ such that $L^\top\eta\,L=\eta $, $\det L=1$ and $a_{00}\geq1 $. This group $SO^+(1,3) $ is a connected matrix Lie group, and its Lie algebra is
\begin{align}
\mathfrak{so}(1,3)=\Big\{\hspace{.03cm} X\in M_4(\mathbb R)\,\big|\,  e^{tX}\in SO^+(1,3),\ \forall\hspace{.02cm}t\in\mathbb R  \hspace{.03cm}\Big\}.
\end{align}
Moreover, the exponential map
\begin{align*}
\exp:\ \mathfrak{so}(1,3)\,&\longrightarrow\, SO^+(1,3)
\\ X\,&\longmapsto\, e^X
\end{align*}
is a surjective, hence $\forall L\in SO^+(1,3),\ L=e^X$ for some $X\in \mathfrak{so}(1,3)$. We have
\begin{align}
\begin{array}{rclcrcl}
\eta & \hspace{-.15cm} = & \hspace{-.15cm} e^{X^\top}\eta\,e^X & \hspace{-.15cm} \Leftrightarrow & \hspace{-.15cm} I_4 & \hspace{-.15cm} = & \hspace{-.15cm} e^{X^\top}\eta\,e^X\eta^{-1}\,=\,e^{X^\top}e^{\eta X\eta^{-1} }
\\ & & & \hspace{-.15cm} \Leftrightarrow & \hspace{-.15cm} X^\top  & \hspace{-.15cm} = & \hspace{-.15cm} -\eta X\eta .\tag1
\end{array}
\end{align}
This implies
\begin{align*}
X\,&=\,\begin{bmatrix}
\,0 & v_1 & v_2 & v_3\,
\\ \,v_1 & 0 & -\theta_3 & \theta_2\,
\\ \,v_2 & \theta_3 & 0 & -\theta_1\,
\\ \,v_3 & -\theta_2 & \theta_1 & 0\,
\end{bmatrix}
\\ &=\,\theta_1 J_1+\theta_2 J_2+\theta_3 J_3+v_1 K_1+v_2K_2+v_3 K_3\,=\,\theta\cdot J+v\cdot K,
\end{align*}
with
\begin{align}
J_1=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0
\\ 0&0&0&-1
\\ 0&0&1&0
\end{pmatrix}\ \ \ J_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0 
\\ 0&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0&0
\\ 0&-1&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\ \ \ J_3=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&0 
\\ 0&0&-1&0 \\ 0&1&0&0
\\ 0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
and
\begin{align}
K_1=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&0&0 \\ 1&0&0&0
\\ 0&0&0&0
\\ 0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\ \ \ K_2=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&1&0 
\\ 0&0&0&0 \\ 1&0&0&0
\\ 0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\ \ \ K_3=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&1 
\\ 0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0
\\ 1&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}
Consider $\theta=0$, one obtains
\begin{align}
L\,&=\,e^{v\cdot K}
\\ &=\,I_4+|v|\,\widehat v\cdot K+ \frac{|v|^2}{2}( v\cdot K)^2+\frac{|v|^3}{6}( v\cdot K)^3+\cdots
\\ &=\,I_4+\left(|v|+\frac{|v|^3}{3!}+\frac{|v|^5}{5!} +\cdots \right)(v\cdot K) + \left(\frac{|v|^2}{2!}+\frac{|v|^4}{4!} +\cdots \right)(v\cdot K)^2
\\ &=\,I_4+\big(\sinh|v|\big)(v\cdot K) +\big(\cosh|v|-1\big)(v\cdot K)^2.\tag2
\end{align}
But I feel like I have done wrong somewhere in my calculation, because in the materials that I consult, the expression of $L$ should be $e^{\psi(\widehat v\cdot K)} $ where $\tanh\psi=|v| $ and thus $|v|<1$. However I have no clue in where of my solution this issue comes from.

I hope someone will help me to clarify my isse or enlight me with some helpful idea. Thanks.

UPDATE

I found a solution for my issue above. Let $\,u=\displaystyle\frac{\tanh|v|}{|v|}\,u$, we have $|u|=tanh|v| $ and  $\widehat{\,v\,}=\widehat u$. Then,
\begin{align*}
\cosh|v|\,&=\,\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-|u|^2}}\,=:\,\gamma,
\\ \sinh|v|\,&=\,\frac{|u|}{\sqrt{1-|u|^2}}\,=\,\gamma|u|
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
L\,&=\,I_4+\gamma|u|\big(\widehat u\cdot K\big)+(\gamma-1)\big(\widehat u\cdot K\big)^2
\\ &=\,I_4+\gamma\big(u\cdot K\big)+\frac{\gamma-1}{|u|^2}\big( u\cdot K\big)^2
\\ &=\, \begin{bmatrix}
\gamma   & \gamma u_1  &  \gamma u_2  &  \gamma u_3 \\ \gamma u_1 &  1+(\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{u_1^2}{u^2}  &  (\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{u_1u_2}{u^2}  &  (\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{u_1u_3}{u^2}   
\\  \gamma u_2 & (\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{u_1u_2}{u^2}  &  1+(\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{u_2^2}{u^2}  &  (\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{u_2u_3}{u^2}  
\\ \,\gamma u_3 & (\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{u_1u_3}{u^2}  &  (\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{u_2u_3}{u^2}  &  1+(\gamma-1)\displaystyle\frac{u_3^2}{u^2} \,
\end{bmatrix}.
\end{align*}

Comment: The exponential map is certainly not injective (look at a rotation in a space-like plane). I am not sure about surjectivity, but I rather doubt it.

Comment: @AndreasCap okay, i think the injectivity may be failed, but I'm sure about the surjectivity

Comment: @AndreasCap so, do we need the injectivity for the proof of (1) ?

Comment: @PermQi Yes you need injectivity for that last step in (1) as you are trying to use $e^X = e^Y \Rightarrow X = Y$ (the converse is true of course). It might still be true but that argument there certainly doesn't prove it.

Comment: I am not sure what your question actually is. If it is proving that $\mathfrak{so}(3,1)$ consists of all matrices such that $X^t=--\eta X\eta$, then this does not need injectivity or surjectivity of the exponential map (which I still doubt). You also don't have to compute the exponential map explicitly for this.

Comment: I definitely don’t think you need $a_{00}\geq 1$, being greater than zero should certainly be enough to preserve time orientation

Comment: You also haven’t shown us any of the actual details of your calculation, so it’s very difficult to see where you mean have gone wrong

Comment: @AndreasCap my goal is to find the explicit expression of the matrix $L=e^X$, the issues are the argument (1) doesn't seem valid, and the result in equation (2) as I said, it doesn't look like what I saw in many materials about general Lorentz boost

Comment: @Chris that is entire of my detailed calculation, I'm not sure which details that you found unclear ?

Comment: @AndreasCap the exponential map is surjective in this case although as you say it isn't relevant to the question. You can prove it by noting $SO^+(3,1) \cong PSL(2,\mathbb{C})$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Surjectiveness_of_exponential_map_for_SO(3,_1)) for example.

Comment: @PermQi As was noted in your last question the formula $e^{\psi (\hat{v}\cdot K)}$ does **not** apply to all Lorentz transformations but specifically only to boosts

Comment: @Callum yes, therefore I only consider the general boost in this article, where I wrote "consider $\theta=0 $".

Comment: @PermQi Sorry I misread that. Then there is no issue with that calculation and indeed it is the one on Wikipedia. I suspect the material you are reading has a different setup or definition of $\hat{v}$ and I imagine it should be $\operatorname{tanh}|v| = \psi$

Comment: @Callum I have just updated my edit